# Satmar and Mishnah Berurah

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, mishnah-berurah, satmar

Do Satmar hassidim follow the Mishnah Berurah? If this is not the case, what sefer or sefarim do they use?

Comment: Just as a provisional, partial answer, I know they don't follow the MB because up until very recently they not only let out shabbos at the R''T zman, they also took it in at that time, which lead to some weird situations.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28941/satmar-derech-halimud

Comment: There are instances where people deviate from the Mishna Brurah and rely on another shittah it dies not mean they don't usually pasken like him

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Interesting first question.  I think that there are other communities, including a few Litvishe yeshivas (but I'm not sure which ones) that look at other authorities ahead of the Mishna Berurah, and I'd also like to know which ones.

Comment: Maybe learning the Sugya (up to late acharonim) and Shimush?

Comment: Do you mean do they rely on him ever or always?

Answer (score 5):

The chassidim in communities  i know, this means poskim and dayanim, who bishita don't view the mishna berurah as the posek achron rely upon the rav shulchan aruch. This is a general attitude, not limited to satmar.

Comment: Do you mean the Shulchan Aruch haRav?

Comment: Yes. But chassidim call it rav shulchan aruch.

Comment: Are you sure Satmar Hassidim follow this Sefer ?

Comment: As much as you are sure they don't follow the mishna berura. I know your question was about satmar in particular, but this a general mindset amongst all chassidim.

Comment: Satmar Chassidim do learn Shulchan Aruch Horav in their Yeshivos and generally follow his rulings.

Comment: Do you know if this is the same for Neturei Karta? I mean the perushim part of NK.

Comment: @Mol-lol. But since you asked, unless i'm mistaken, NK consider themselves talmidei haGra. In fact the popular siddur nusach haGra was put out by one of the founders of NK. While many satmars look the same and have the same antistate idumbology, its a different group completely.

Comment: Thanks but it does not answer my question. Do NK follow the MB?

Comment: @Mol probably not. They follow the Gra.

Comment: Which Sefer is their main halacha book then?

Comment: The shulchan aruch c/o the gra.

Comment: The Biur haGra then?

Comment: @Mol- You are really into this? Its not so simple. The Gra apparently didn't write much himself. All we have from him is from his talmidim. That being said its understandable that there are various traditions. The most famous book of his minhagim is Maaseh Rav, quoted at times in the mishna berurah. There are instances where the Maaseh Rav conflicts the biur hagra, say by mayim migulim, thats a famous one. But there are other works by other talmidim. I assume the N.K. have their own tradition. Just like Yeshiva Chaim Berlin and Rav Shturnbach. All claiming to carry on the torch of the Gra.

Comment: Thanks. And by the way, I find it disgusting when you called their ideology "idumbology". Read Vayoel Moshe and you will understand how dumb YOU are.

Comment: Its ok. I've been called worse by better people. I also know Rabbi Frankel who fed Reb Yoel all the lashon hara about the state before he wrote Vayoel Moshe, so I know nothing in there was written with the clear objectiveness a seffer deserves.

Comment: And its very telling of your personality that you waited to insult me untill after you attained all the information you wanted from me.

Comment: @user6591 And yet the Baba Sali referred to the Vayoel Moshe as "kulo emes," so it seems that that tzaddik disagrees with you on its objectiveness.

Comment: @Yehuda I would appreciate seeing a link or a sourceable quote before responding to that.

Comment: @user6591 I read it in the biography, I'd have to get my hands on it again to look up the page.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in a Yeshiva with Satmar guys. By Halacha Seder they learnt Mishnah Berira. Reb Leibel Willger isn't Satmar but he uses Mishnah Berira all the time!