# Chassidic equivalent to Nefesh HaChaim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, nefesh-hachaim

Rav Chaim of Volozhin in his famous work Nefesh HaChaim explains things according to the Litvish philosophy, views etc. Is there a Chassidic work which deals with the same topics as Nefesh HaChaim?

Topics which the book discusses is as follows: Section one is about the nature of the soul and man's role in creation. Section two is about prayer, its true nature as directed meditation and what prayer really does in the context of God's plan: bind the worlds together and nourish them from above. It also describes how the process of repentance operates in re-establishing one's connection to God. Section three is about the nature of God's presence in the world, reconciling unity and duality. The Chapters section between sections three and four addresses how the evil inclination strategizes to divert us. Section four is about the special nature of Torah and the importance of our involvement with it.

Comment: Does anyone know anything about Shefa Chaim? This could be what you're looking for.

Comment: @HachamGabriel what work are you referring to by the Klausenburger Rebbe?

Comment: I think so, because in my Yeshiva they are very into it and it seems to talk about learning and stuff.

Comment: What is the name of the work you are referring to?

Comment: Shefa Chaim by the Sanzer Rebbi.

Comment: Where can I find it because I am coming up empty on google?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/home.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nefesh HaChaim is generally considered (as I understand it) to be a "Litvish" response to Hassidism's Tanya. Though the former also addresses "derech halimud."

Comment: can you think of any other Chassidic work which encompasses the same topics?

Comment: Chabad derech halimud: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/chabad-gemara-learning/7952#7952