# Order of Gemara In Lubavitch Yeshivos

Tags: torah-study, talmud-gemara, chabad, yeshiva-school

What is the specific order of Masechetas that are generally learned in Lubavitcher Yeshivas?

What is next year's Mesechta?

Comment: The order can be found [here](http://haoros.com/shiurim/index.asp?c=2), but it's now holding in Shabbos

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4798/2699

Answer (score 2):

This year is Shabbos, followed by Gittin, Bava Basra, Kesubos, Bava Kamah, Pesachim, Kidushin and Bava Metziyah.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, user3319, and thanks for your answer, which would be more valuable to the rest of us if you'd [edit] in how you know. (E.g., "That's the order mentioned in the _sicha_ of 10 _Sh'vat_ 5731" or "That's my personal experience; I've learned in a Lubavitch _y'shiva_ for 27 years".) I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. You may also wish to [change your username](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/3319) (unless you're attached to the number 3319).