# Which are the "Yeshivish Masechtos"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, yeshiva-school, chareidim-ultraorthodox

Generally speaking there seems to be a list of "Yeshivish Masechtos" (masechtos usually studied in Yeshivot) and specific Perakim which are learnt in Chareidi mainstream Yeshivot. 
For instance, in the Mir and BMG which פרקים do they do?

Comment: Define "Yeshivish." ....I've voted to close this question as "primarily opinion based," because it is. There is no one list of "Yeshivish Masechtos" (you'd be surprised at which masechtos some "yeshivish" places study). You may be better off asking what masechtos a particular yeshiva studies.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35213/order-of-gemara-in-lubavitch-yeshivos

Comment: A lot of high schools do one masechta b'iyun and another for bekius (usually a shorter one from Moed). And a lot of yeshivos have a first seder perek and a second seder perek.

Answer (score 8):

Yeshivish mesechtos are typically the masechtos learned in high school because they are the ones that are more involving (lots of lomdus) and can train a person how to properly learn gemara.

Very often yeshivos have a machzor, cycle of 8 masechtos:

- (1,2) יבמות
- (1,3) כתובות
- (1,2,10) נדרים
- (1,4,6,8) גיטין
- (1,2,3) קידושין
- (1,2,3,9) בבא קמא
- (1,2,3,9) בבא מציעא
- (1,2,3,8) בבא בתרא.

Obviously every yeshiva has its own way of doing things, but these are fairly common.

Comment: Sanhedrin not one of them?

Comment: sanhedrin, pesachim, makot, shevuot, suca

Comment: Anyone have a more extensive list including the others mentioned by Kouty?

Comment: It looks like 6 and 8 were intended to go with B"K, not Kiddushin.

Comment: left out 7th perek of Bava Kama

Comment: 8th perek of b.m. more than the 9th

Answer (score 4):

In Lubavitch, the [cycle](http://haoros.com/shiurim/index.asp?c=2) is Kiddushin, Bava Metzia, Shabbos, Gittin, Bava Basra, Kesuvos, Bava Kamma, Pesachim, Kesuvos (in that order).

All focusing on the first chapter, except Kesuvos focusing on the second.

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no canonical cycle accepted by all, many traditional Yeshivas have a cycle involving the following tractates:

- יבמות
- כתובות
- נדרים
- גיטין
- קידושין
- בבא קמא
- בבא מציעא
- בבא בתרא

Some Yeshivos (primarily in Eretz Yisroel) also do:

- סנהדרין
- מכות
- פסחים
- סוכה

Brisk style Yeshivos generally focus on Kodshim oriented mesechtos:

- זבחים
- מנחות
- בכורות
- תמורה
- מעילה
- יומא
- נזיר

Note: While the main tractates are fairly consistent amongst most Yeshivos built on the Lithuanian-model, the Perakim chosen to study in depth vary widely.

Comment: I've somewhere heard that Hungarian yeshivot put emphasis on Seder Moed, but I can't find a source for it ever since.